# Unity 2d Character moves and jumps to specific positions with UI buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

In a simple 2d project in which my player can move to the right and left on x and can also jump to the right and left in height with two other buttons. The problem is, that the player is not supposed to move freely. By pressing one of the buttons the player should only go to the next specific point, so that the player always stops at six different positions on x (while on y he is free and as high as the platform he is currently standing on). To be able to jump realistically, the player must have gravity and a collider to be able to land on the platforms (and move single platforms horizontal).
Thanks to the tutorial which @TEEBQNE linked in the comments I could finally realise this with Unitys Rigidbody2D and the following script. The problem is that the gravity is now behaving strangely. The player only moves down very slowly and in the process pushes Gameobjects underneath it through others. The player has a Dynamic Rigidbody2D with a gravity scale of 2 and a capsule collider 2d. Is that a problem with the script or with the components in the players inspector?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject posChecker1;
    public GameObject posChecker2;
    public GameObject posChecker3;
    public GameObject posChecker4;
    public GameObject posChecker5;
    public GameObject posChecker6;

    public bool go; //Player is allowed to move
    public bool grounded; //Player is allowed to jump
    public string moveDirection;
    public float horizVel = 0; //Movement along x
    public float verticVel = 0; //Jump

    public int laneNum = 3; //Player starts on lane 3!!
    public bool rightButtonMove = false;//
    public bool leftButtonMove = false;//
    public bool rightButtonJump = false;//
    public bool leftButtonJump = false;//



    //Animation
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private Animator animator;

    private void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        posChecker1.SetActive(true);//GameObject.Find("PositionChecker1").SetActive(true);
        posChecker2.SetActive(true);
        posChecker3.SetActive(true); //Player start on lane 3!!
        posChecker4.SetActive(true);
        posChecker5.SetActive(true);
        posChecker6.SetActive(true);

        laneNum = 3;
        go = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Raycast
        int playerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("PositionChecker");// !!!

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up) * 50f, Color.green);
        RaycastHit2D hitCheck = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up), 50f, playerMask);

        //Only the checker objects in the rows next to the player are active
        if (laneNum == 1)
        {
            posChecker1.SetActive(false);
            posChecker2.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 2)
        {
            posChecker1.SetActive(true);
            posChecker2.SetActive(false);
            posChecker3.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 3)
        {
            posChecker2.SetActive(true);
            posChecker3.SetActive(false);
            posChecker4.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 4)
        {
            posChecker3.SetActive(true);
            posChecker4.SetActive(false);
            posChecker5.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 5)
        {
            posChecker4.SetActive(true);
            posChecker5.SetActive(false);
            posChecker6.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 6)
        {
            posChecker5.SetActive(true);
            posChecker6.SetActive(false);
        }

        //Movement
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(horizVel, verticVel, 0);


        //Raycast
        if (hitCheck)
        {
            
            if (moveDirection == "l" && horizVel != 0)
            {
                laneNum -= 1;
            }
            if (moveDirection == "r" && horizVel != 0)
            {
                laneNum += 1;
            }
            go = true;
            horizVel = 0;
            verticVel = 0;
            grounded = true;
        }
        if (horizVel == 0)
            moveDirection = "";


        //Animation
        bool flipSprite = (spriteRenderer.flipX ? (horizVel > 0.01f) : (horizVel < 0.01f));
        if (flipSprite)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
        }

        animator.SetBool("grounded", grounded); // -->Jump
        animator.SetFloat("velocityX", Mathf.Abs(horizVel));

    }


    //Button Input
    public void RightButton() //
    {
        if (laneNum < 6 && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "r";
            go = false;
            horizVel = 4;
        }
    }
    public void LeftButton()//
    {
        if (laneNum > 1 && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "l";
            go = false;
            horizVel = -4;
        }
    }
    public void RightJump()//
    {
        if (laneNum < 6 && grounded && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "r";
            horizVel = 4;
            verticVel = 7;
            go = false;
            grounded = false;
        }
    }
    public void LeftJump()//
    {
        if (laneNum > 1 && grounded && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "l";
            horizVel = -4;
            verticVel = 7;
            go = false;
            grounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some relevant code instead of linking the entire Brackye's 2D controller repo? Is your issue that you are moving by using `transform.position += new vector(1, 0, 0)` and your character is moving into walls or other obstacles in your scene?

Comment: It was an issue when I was using `transform.position`. So I tried it now with Rigidbodys and Colliders. The movement is working and it is not moving into other obstacles anymore (also gravity works), but the issue which I am having now is that it is moving as long as I am pressing the button. My goal, however, is that the player moves to the next fixed position on x by just clicking the button once.

Comment: You want it to only move on a click not a hold? And want it to stop moving once it hits the new position?

Comment: Yes, so the player can only be in the middle of one of six vertical rows (only the horizontal position should be fix, the player should be able to jump freely along the y axis).

Comment: To accomplish exactly what you'd like would take an overhaul of the codw you've given. If you want to make an endless runner like Subway Surfer try [this tutorial](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4UezTfGBADC6Li-b8uPptn1JsgFzUoXs)

Comment: I watched the tutorial and it was really helpful. However instead of stopping the player after a certain period of time, I modified the script and was able to solve the problem with raycasts. I now have an empty object with a collider above each row. the empty in the players row is always deactivated. the player then runs until the raycast hits the next empty object. The script is working but now the gravity behaves strangely. The player only moves down very slowly and in the process pushes Gameobjects underneath it through others. The player has a Dynamic Rigidbody2D with a gravity scale of 2

Comment: @TEEBQNE you were right about the overhaul of my code. I have edited my question and posted the new script.

Comment: Gravity can be floaty due to a few reasons. The default of gravity in any project is 9.81 m/s as that is the value of gravity on Earth. You can change this value instead of changing the gravity value to get a snappier feel to how gravity should change in your game. Go to **Edit->ProjectSettings->Physics** or **Physics2D**. There should be a field called `gravity` that reads `-9.81`. I would first try to increase this value.

Comment: As for the character pushing other objects through other objects, I would need to see how the other objects are set up in the inspector as well as a video of it happening. Something like this should not happen unless one object is pushed through another in a single frame. Unity's physics by default is `Discrete`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The gravity is working normally for the Boxes. Just the players gravity is behaving strangely. I have uploaded a video of the player pushing through boxes and pictures from the inspectors to this [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NiKWQ9h-U_EeZzqjo7Kyr11j2O9d4GUl?usp=sharing). As you can see the player is only pushing through boxes and not through the ground object (so maybe the boxes are the problem and I changed something important in their inspector by accident).

Comment: I would reset the BoxCollider2D in the box prefab. Click the three dots on the collider component and select reset. There is also a warning on the ground object about not having a composite collider so you can uncheck that field on that component. It is possible your animation is causing this issue try disabling the animation and trying without it. If it is still happening check if all of your colliders are placed properly on the objects.

Comment: I have tried everything, but it is still not working. In the final game, of course, more than one box will fall. This is controlled by a script, which I switched off for the video. But when several boxes fall on top of each other, they bounce up again, as if they had a kind of soft body. I wonder what caused this and could this be the reason for this pushing through?

Comment: I have also uploaded another video so you can see what I mean by the bouncing

Comment: Long shot, but I noticed that the mass of the boxes is 0.0001. I would increase this to 1.

Comment: Rewatching the first clip, it almost seems however your push code is working is the issue. When you push a block, it then makes your player float and disregard collisions. In the new video the boxes hit the player on the head and have no problem staying on top of them.

Comment: I have increased the box mass to 1 and it is not pushing through anymore (although the boxes are still bouncing, but that is not a big deal). I also deactivated the movement script and the player's gravity returned to normal. This means that somehow the move script must actually have an effect on the gravity.

Comment: It might be due to how or where you are calling your jump as you are continually setting your Y component of velocity

Comment: You are right the `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(horizVel, verticVel, 0);` in the Update Method must cause the problem. I have tried to set `verticVel = Physic2D.gravity.y` while the player is not jumping, but then the gravity gets like added to the gravity of the Rigidbody so the player pushes into the ground. I can not figure out how to solve this issue. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I would advise to not affect velocity directly when jumping. Instead, use [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html). Directly changing velocity in two places causes unexpected results which is what you are seeing here.

Comment: I have now tried it for a while with AddForce but that didn't really work. I have now managed to solve the problem differently by simply setting `verticVel = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y;` when the player doesn't jump. The jumping movement could still be a little more natural, but in itself the movement now works. Thanks a lot for your help! I have seen that there is a reputation system. So if you want to answer the question, I have shared the working code with you in the [Google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NiKWQ9h-U_EeZzqjo7Kyr11j2O9d4GUl?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad I was able to help in some way and that you figured out your issue!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Player Position x
    public GameObject posChecker1;
    public GameObject posChecker2;
    public GameObject posChecker3;
    public GameObject posChecker4;
    public GameObject posChecker5;
    public GameObject posChecker6;
    public int laneNum = 3; //Player starts on lane 3!!

    //Player Position y
    public float yPos1;
    public float yPos2;
    public Transform player;

    //Movement Variables
    public bool go; //Player is allowed to move
    public bool grounded; //Player is allowed to jump
    public string moveDirection;
    public float horizVel = 0; //Movement along x
    public float verticVel = 0; //Jump

    //Animation
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    private Animator animator;

    private void Awake()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        posChecker1.SetActive(true);//GameObject.Find("PositionChecker1").SetActive(true);
        posChecker2.SetActive(true);
        posChecker3.SetActive(true); //Player start on lane 3!!
        posChecker4.SetActive(true);
        posChecker5.SetActive(true);
        posChecker6.SetActive(true);

        laneNum = 3;
        go = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Raycast
        int playerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("PositionChecker");// !!!

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up) * 50f, Color.green);
        RaycastHit2D hitCheck = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up), 50f, playerMask);

        //Only the checker objects in the rows next to the player are active
        if (laneNum == 1)
        {
            posChecker1.SetActive(false);
            posChecker2.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 2)
        {
            posChecker1.SetActive(true);
            posChecker2.SetActive(false);
            posChecker3.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 3)
        {
            posChecker2.SetActive(true);
            posChecker3.SetActive(false);
            posChecker4.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 4)
        {
            posChecker3.SetActive(true);
            posChecker4.SetActive(false);
            posChecker5.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 5)
        {
            posChecker4.SetActive(true);
            posChecker5.SetActive(false);
            posChecker6.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (laneNum == 6)
        {
            posChecker5.SetActive(true);
            posChecker6.SetActive(false);
        }

        //Movement
        if (grounded)
        {
            verticVel = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y;
        }
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(horizVel, /*GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y*/verticVel, 0);
        //Jump
        yPos2 = player.transform.position.y;
        if ((yPos2 - 2) >= yPos1 && !grounded)
        {
            if (moveDirection == "l")
                horizVel = -4;
            if (moveDirection == "r")
                horizVel = 4;
            verticVel = verticVel * 0.95f;
        }

        //Raycast
        if (hitCheck)
        {
            if (moveDirection == "l" && horizVel != 0)
            {
                laneNum -= 1;
            }
            if (moveDirection == "r" && horizVel != 0)
            {
                laneNum += 1;
            }
            go = true;
            horizVel = 0;
            verticVel = 0;
            grounded = true;
        }
        if (horizVel == 0 && grounded)
            moveDirection = "";


        //Animation
        bool flipSprite = (spriteRenderer.flipX ? (horizVel > 0.01f) : (horizVel < 0.01f));
        if (flipSprite)
        {
            spriteRenderer.flipX = !spriteRenderer.flipX;
        }

        animator.SetBool("grounded", grounded); // -->Jump
        animator.SetFloat("velocityX", Mathf.Abs(horizVel));

    }


    //Button Input
    public void RightButton() //
    {
        if (laneNum < 6 && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "r";
            go = false;
            horizVel = 4;
        }
    }
    public void LeftButton()//
    {
        if (laneNum > 1 && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "l";
            go = false;
            horizVel = -4;
        }
    }
    public void RightJump()//
    {
        if (laneNum < 6 && grounded && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "r";
            verticVel = 5;
            go = false;
            grounded = false;
            //
            yPos1 = player.transform.position.y;
            Debug.Log(yPos1);
            //
        }
    }
    public void LeftJump()//
    {
        if (laneNum > 1 && grounded && go)
        {
            moveDirection = "l";
            verticVel = 5;
            go = false;
            grounded = false;
            //
            yPos1 = player.transform.position.y;
            Debug.Log(yPos1);
            //
        }
    }
}
```